# How to change values in Web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Google apps script with doGet function:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Copy').evaluate();
}
```

There is string in file Copy:

```
<span id="label"></span>
```

I need to change text of this from GS (I have big function and need change text 4-5 times). I tried to find info about doPost()and UrlFetchApp.fetch(), but i don't understand what i need to do to change some text in web app. (and how to use do Post() generally)

I read about templates https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates but they can change text only 1 time, in doGet..

Simply put i need to give user info about status of executing my function.

Comment: You could use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` to update the status of your function in regular intervals. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: Check this [doGet and doPost Tutorial](http://googleappscripting.com/doget-dopost-tutorial-examples/). The [`ContentService.createTextOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service) method is the most basic way to return content from a GET request but is the building block for most other types of content. The [`TextOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) objects created by this method returns a response of type, text/plain by default, but can be set to ATOM, CSV, ICAL, JAVASCRIPT, JSON, RSS, TEXT, VCARD, and XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [contentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

Google spreadsheet can help you to save data.
With your script you can save data on the map and use dom to show the data, or save data on the spreadsheet and display data with SpreadsheetApp.